# which package does 'import twitter' import?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twitter, python-import

I have both twitter 1.17.0 and python-twitter 2.2 installed. They both use

```
import twitter
```

How do I know which one is being imported?

Comment: Make your choice and uninstall one of them to avoid any further confusions.

Comment: Try `print twitter.__file__` and find out

Comment: Why did that get down voted? Here's what I got: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_file_'
I also tried ._version_ before posting this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to find out where the module is defined with [inspect.getfile()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile) function like this:

```
import twitter
from inspect import getfile

print(getfile(twitter))
```